# Expected type tuple in function

Tags: python

My program implements a generic coerce_apply function that, given the name of an action and the two arguments as objects of types, units of measurement calculates and returns the result of the action on the arguments, by converting one of the objects to the type of the other object

Copy all the code to see the error that is in the key and I can not solve

```
class Centimeters(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Centimeters({0})'.format(self.val)
class Inches(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Inches({0})'.format(self.val)
class Feets(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Feets({0})'.format(self.val)
def Inches_to_Centimeters(C):
    return Centimeters(C.Inches*2.54)
def add_Centimeters(s,o):
    return Centimeters('%.20f' % (s.val + o.val))
def add_Inches(s,o):
    return Inches('%.20f' % (s.val + o.val))
def add_Inches_Centimeters(i,c):
    return add_Inches(i,centimeter_to_inche(c))
def add_Centimeters_Inches(c, i):
    return add_Centimeters(c, inche_to_centimeter(i))
def type_tag(x):
    return type_tag.tags[type(x)]
type_tag.tags = {Centimeters: 'cen', Inches: 'inc', Feets:  'fee'}
centimeter_to_inche = lambda x: Centimeters(x.val * 1/2.54)
inche_to_centimeter = lambda x: Inches(x.val * 2.54)
coercions = {('inc', 'cen'): inche_to_centimeter}
def coerce_apply(operator_name, x, y):
    tx, ty = type_tag(x), type_tag(y)
    if tx != ty:
        if (tx, ty) in coercions:
            tx, x = ty, coercions[(tx, ty)](x)
        elif (ty, tx) in coercions:
            ty, y = tx, coercions[(ty, tx)](y)
        else:
            return 'No coercion possible.'
    assert tx == ty
    key = (operator_name, tx)
    return coerce_apply.implementations[key](x, y)
coerce_apply.implementations = {}
coerce_apply.implementations[('add', ('inc', 'cen'))] = add_Inches_Centimeters
print(coerce_apply('add',Inches(1),Centimeters(150)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is convoluted - normally you use classes to combine data with methods to allow f.e. the Centimeter class to handle its own conversion and addition to other units.

You get

> ```
>   File "t.py", line 46, in <module>
>     print(coerce_apply('add',Inches(1),Centimeters(150)))
>   File "t.py", line 43, in coerce_apply
>     return coerce_apply.implementations[key](x, y)
> KeyError: ('add', 'cen')
> ```

because you are missing the conversion to add centimeters to centimerters in your code.

You can fix it like so (I removed Feets):

```
class Centimeters(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Centimeters({0})'.format(self.val)

    # enable self-addition by other centimeters
    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Centimeters):
            raise Exception("Bad __add__ call")
        self.val += other.val
        return Centimeters(self.val + other.val)

class Inches(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Inches({0})'.format(self.val)

    # enable self-addition by other Inches
    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Inches):
            raise Exception("Bad __add__ call")
        return Inches(self.val + other.val)
```

> ```
> def Inches_to_Centimeters(C):
>     return Centimeters(C.Inches*2.54)
> def add_Centimeters(s,o):
>     return Centimeters('%.20f' % (s.val + o.val))
> def add_Inches(s,o):
>     return Inches('%.20f' % (s.val + o.val))
> def add_Inches_Centimeters(i,c):
>     return add_Inches(i,centimeter_to_inche(c))
> def add_Centimeters_Inches(c, i):
>     return add_Centimeters(c, inche_to_centimeter(i))
> def type_tag(x):
>     return type_tag.tags[type(x)]
> type_tag.tags = {Centimeters: 'cen', Inches: 'inc', Feets:  'fee'}
> centimeter_to_inche = lambda x: Centimeters(x.val * 1/2.54)
> inche_to_centimeter = lambda x: Inches(x.val * 2.54)
> coercions = {('inc', 'cen'): inche_to_centimeter}
>
> def coerce_apply(operator_name, x, y):
>     tx, ty = type_tag(x), type_tag(y)
>     if tx != ty:
>         if (tx, ty) in coercions:
>             tx, x = ty, coercions[(tx, ty)](x)
>         elif (ty, tx) in coercions:
>             ty, y = tx, coercions[(ty, tx)](y)
>         else:
>             return 'No coercion possible.'
>     assert tx == ty
>     key = (operator_name, (tx,ty))
>     return coerce_apply.implementations[key](x, y)
> ```

```
coerce_apply.implementations = {}
coerce_apply.implementations[('add', ('inc', 'cen'))] = add_Inches_Centimeters
# add self-addition via classes __add__ method to "conversion"
coerce_apply.implementations[('add', ('cen', 'cen'))] = Centimeters.__add__

print(coerce_apply('add',Inches(1),Centimeters(150)))
```

Output:

```
Centimeters(152.54)
```